# When moving to Mac from iOS in Objective-C development, NSIntegers give type matching errors

Tags: objective-c, ios, types, type-conversion

I've been working on an iOS project for some time now, and I've recently decided to port the code to a Mac project. Because I've chosen to use NSInteger in my code, and NSInteger is a environment-dependent typecast, it means that my variables are different types on the iOS and Mac apps.

When I run the test suite on the Mac, all my STAssertEquals calls fail with the error "Type mismatch --" because the types don't match:

```
NSInteger foo = 1;
STAssertEquals(foo, 1, nil); // Test fails!!
```

Typecasting my scalars seems to work, but this seems really messy:

```
NSInteger foo = 1;
STAssertEquals(foo, (NSInteger)1, nil); // Succeeds, but is ugly!!
```

Am I missing something here? I'm starting to suspect that the decision to use NSIntegers was a poor choice.

Update: Perhaps [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405006/nslog-specifier-for-nsinteger) is related. It seems to support typecasting scalars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of NSInteger is probably the right choice, but it does cause some issues with STAssertEquals.

STAssertEquals fails if the two objects have different [Objective-C type encodings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html)

A lone `1` will be interpreted by the C compiler as a (signed int), which has type encoding "i".

These macros would also fail:

```
unsigned u = 1;
STAssertEquals(u, 1, nil); // Fails because u is type "I" (unsigned int) and 1 is type "i" (int)

char c = 1;
STAssertEquals(c, 1, nil); // Fails because c is type "c" (signed char) and 1 is type "i" (signed int)
```

To make the compiler use a different type for `1`, you would add a suffix such as `1U` for (unsigned int), `1UL` for (unsigned long) or `1L` for (long).

NSInteger is defined to be the same size as pointers, which is dependent on the device architecture.  On 32-bit Mac OS X and iOS, NSInteger is type (signed int), or "i".  On 64-bit Mac OS X, it is type long, or "q".  (64-bit Mac OS X is a LP64 architecture, which means that **L**ongs and **P**ointers are both **64**-bits wide)

Thus, the left side of your STAssertEquals is a "q", whereas the right side is "i", causing the type mismatch.

Your solution of using `(NSInteger) 1` seems to accurately represent what you want - test an NSInteger variable against an NSInteger constant of value 1.

Comment: I would assume the following idea would almost certainly bad, but I figured I'd ask: Is there a way to force the compiler to treat untyped scalars such as "1" as NSIntegers?

Comment: I don't believe so.  The compiler will promote a significantly large integer constant to a (signed long) or (signed long long), but I don't believe there is a way to get this behavior for free (even if there was, you probably wouldn't want to do that :) )